# Angular5 nested observable-subscriptions to a single observable

Tags: angular, nested, observable, subscription

I have the following code in the **service layer** and I have two questions:

```
return this.equipmentService.getEquipment(this.id) //returns subscription
  .subscribe((equipment : Equipment) =>
  {
    this.getEquipmentTags(); //returns subscription
    this.getPredictions(); //returns subscription
  });
});
```

1. In the code, I have subscribed to equipmentService.getEquipment observable and
   now it returns Subscription object - how can I make it an observable object
   again so it can be handled again in the **business layer** for example
2. How can I be aware that all inner observables finished their tasks and trigger an event (or call a method or create another observable that I can subscribe later in the code)

Comment: depends on what you want to do with the results, there are choices: [Combining-Observables](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables)

Comment: for question 1: I want to return the equipment, and for 2 - I don't care about the result - all I need is to know they finished

Comment: I checked the link you gave, but it is about observables, and I don't know how to turn the Subscription object to observable again.

Comment: I am thinking you want `map` (or `flatmap`) instead of `subscribe` in the code shown. That way you only deal with the `Observable` type. You can then add `subscribe` again after to force it to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not fire the subscription too early, as @igor point out and you (`this.equipmentService.getEquipment(this.id)` do not returns a subscription, it returns an Observable, because in other way you cannot subscribe to it), use `concatMap` (and pipeable operators) to get chained you Observables.

```
getChainedObservables() {
  return this.equipmentService.getEquipment(this.id)
    .pipe(
      concatMap((equipment : Equipment) => this.getEquipmentTags()),
      concatMap(() => this.getPredictions())
    );
}
```

**then call it,**

```
this.getChainedObservables().subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for are Subjects.

A Subject can act as Observable or Observer, so you can both subscribe to it or call the `.next()` to send events. They also contain useful methods such as `complete()` or `error()` that allows you to control the status of a particular subject.

Here is [a useful article](https://netbasal.com/understanding-subjects-in-rxjs-55102a190f3) that covers the basis of the topic.